# Apache servers redirect to one specific server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver, apache2

Is there any solution to redirect all these urls to one url without creating a specific server and then redirect it from that server to server I want. I was wondering to do that with `.htaccess` but since that server doesn't exist then how I can execute htaccess there...

```
http://example.com  -----|
http://www.example.com --|-------- to: https://www.example.com
https://example.com -----|
```

**.conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ServerName www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile       ...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile    ...

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You mean you don't want to create 3 `VirtualHost` entries?

Comment: I was wondering if there isn't any easier option, like using htaccess... instead creating 3 entries

Comment: Well you will still need 2 entries. One for port `443 ` and another for post 80. Then of course .htaccess can handle rest like `http -> https` and `non-www to www`

Comment: Do I have to create .htaccess for each entry?

Comment: No, just a single `.htaccess`

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that I issued wrongly certificate to "`*.exaple.com`"

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess shoud look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Configuration might need to be changed according to how your network is setup, for example if you have a load-balancer in front of your apache or according to the apache version you're running.